# LightSquid ldap authentication fails

Tags: linux, proxy, ldap, squid

I have a lightsquid server to generate reports about Internet use.

It is integrated with LDAP server.

I cant login in lightsquid web page.

```
cat /var/log/apache2/error.log

Thu Dec 26 13:54:04 2013] [info] [client 192.168.0.66] [29087] auth_ldap authenticate: user john.doe authentication failed; URI /lightsquid/ [ldap_search_ext_s() for user failed][Operations error]
```

The web browser shows the "Error 500" page.

Apache lightsquid conf:

```
Alias /lightsquid /usr/lib/cgi-bin/lightsquid/
<Location "/lightsquid/">
 AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

 AuthType Basic
 AuthName "Dominio ACME"
 AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
 AuthBasicProvider ldap
 AuthUserFile /dev/null
 require ldap-user john.doe jane.doe

 AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=SquidUser,OU=IT,OU=ACME,DC=acme,DC=local"
 AuthLDAPBindPassword "squiduserp@$$"
 AuthLDAPURL "ldap://domcontro1.acme.local/DC=acme,DC=local?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"

 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
 Allow from 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0

</Location>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this line on /etc/ldap/ldap.conf file:

```
REFERRALS off
```

to disable the underlying SDK's referral chasing state and now lightsquid works!